# Strange result of DeleteCases in an association

Tags: bugs, pattern-matching, associations

**Bug introduced in 10.1.0 and fixed in 10.3.1**

---

The function `DeleteCases` can be used for associations, also with level specification. Here is an example where some values are associations:

```
asc = Association["a" -> Association[], "b" -> Association["c" -> Association[1 -> 1]]]

(* <|a -> <||>, b -> <|c -> <|1 -> 1|>|>|> *)
```

Deleting on level 1 works:

```
DeleteCases[asc, _Association]

(* <||> *)
```

Deleting on level 2 works as well:

```
DeleteCases[asc, _Association, {2}]

(* <|a -> <||>, b -> <||>|> *)
```

But deleting on both levels does not return what I would expect:

```
DeleteCases[asc, _Association, {1,2}]

(* <|a -> <||>|> *)
```

I cannot figure out why this happens. Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

Comment: With MMa 10.1.0 under Win7 x64 I get `<||>` both for `DeleteCases[asc, _Association, {1, 2}]` and `DeleteCases[asc, _Association, 2]`. Which version do you use?

Comment: @Alexey. Many thanks for your prompt reaction. I use version 10.1.0 on Windows 32-bit. When I restarted my computer and verified the result with a fresh kernel, I was shocked to see the same output as yours. I ran into this problem quite often the last few days, and fortunately I could edit my question such that the unexpect result now also appears with a fresh kernel. Do you mind to test it once again?

Comment: With you updated example I get the same output as yours. Looks like a bug indeed.